# Como alterar um chave primary key para constraint Auto_increment

Tags: sql, auto-incremento, constraint

Criei a seguinte tabela

```
create table if not exists cursos(
nome varchar (30) not null unique,
descicao text,
carga int unsigned,
totaulas int,
ano year default '2018'

)default charset = utf8;
```

Após adicionei uma **PK**

```
alter table cursos
add primary key (idCurso);
alter table cursos add column idCurso varchar(10) after nome;
```

Minha dificuldade como tornar ela agora `auto_increment`

Primeira tentativa:

```
 alter table cursos add constraint idCursos varchar(10)  auto_increment;
```

**help!**

Comment: Alguma destas duas soluções funcionaram ? Sequer o SGBD foi informado.

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

```
ALTER TABLE `banco`.`tabela` 
MODIFY COLUMN `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST;
```

Comment: `banco`.`tabela` tem que setar o nome do banco?

Answer (score 0):

o auto_increment não é uma constraint, por isso não funcionou com seu comando! o código informado pelo rLinhares está correto, mas tu não precisa setar o banco, caso por exemplo tu já esteja 'dentro' dele.

o comando que eu recomendo:

```
alter table cursos modify idCurso smallint first auto_increment;
```

- vai adicionar o auto_increment, mudando o seu tipo *necessario* pois varchar não é auto_increment
- vai adicionar a coluna idCurso para a primeira posição de colunas.